# How can I enter metadata into a qgiscloud project

Tags: qgis, metadata, online

I published a project into qgiscloud: https://qgiscloud.com/tragewegen/IDEAproject_DonkeyMobileBlackCarbon.

I want metadata to be published in the metadatatab next to the legendtab.  Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like a question for support@qgiscloud.com

Comment: I asked them the same.  If I get an answer, I post it over here.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at plugins
http://code.google.com/p/qgis-features-metadata-editor/source/browse/trunk/FeaturesMetadataEditor/metadata.txt?spec=svn10&r=10